# CANBUS Masking and Filtering

Tags: c, embedded, can, at-commands

I am using a module to convert CAN to UART. This module has 2 programmable masks and 6 programmable filters.

There are 13 message IDs that come in over the CAN bus and I only want 9 of them. The IDs are as follows.

The messages I dont want :

```
 - 0x404
 - 0x6f1
 - 0x114
 - 0x11c
```

The ones I do want :

```
 - 0x36C
 - 0x33C 
 - 0x34C 
 - 0x35C 
 - 0x314 
 - 0x31C 
 - 0x324 
 - 0x32C 
 - 0x37C
```

I have found masking quite confusing and I would love if someone could help me better my understanding of it. Would I set my mask to `0x3ff` or `0x300`? Then the `0x11c` messages will come in?

Comment: If the device excludes anything with non-mask bits, i.e. keeps anything where `!(~MASK & ID) == true` then  `MASK = 0x3ff` will keep everything you want to keep, but I think you would still get the 0x11c and 0x114

Comment: if it includes only codes with all the mask bits, then  `MASK = 0x300` and you're good

Comment: I need to make sure I dont have 0x3ff coming through unfortunately. I will try 0x300 now. Thanks :)

Comment: Can't hurt to try! To make the question clearer for future readers, could you describe the logic of how the mask works? I described two possibilities, no idea which one your device actually implements, or if it is something else entirely.

Comment: Hey Pete, I just tried 0x300 and all I got back was the 0x404 message.The module I am using is this : https://docs.longan-labs.cc/1030001/#set-mask. I have linked directly to the set mask part of the module. Hope that helps the clarity.

Trying 0x3FF rejected all messages oddly. Appreciate the help once again.

Comment: Ok, then we know the mask is not behaving like the second hypothesis... Will take a look at that ... cryptic docs :-(

Comment: oh okay. for the bits what you set to one, you have to also enable filters. also mask might be inverted.

Comment: try `MASK = ~(0x300)`

Comment: I was struggling to decipher it. Appreciate the help. I am new to CANBUS and have a deadline I am trying to meet. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I looked up docs for a completely different device. Did you understand my notation? take 0x300 and bitwise invert it. Good luck!

Comment: no, take 0x0000300 and flip each bit.

Comment: So trying that the inverse is 0x3ff. In this case I get no messages. 

I did find this : http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~eg/tele/CanbusIDandMask.html

Which seems to explain it but I am trying to convert it and cant really figure it out.

Comment: ok... so similar to "example 2" there...  try `filter = 0x300 , mask = 0x1fffff00`

Comment: Pete, Thank you very much. Filter at 0x300 and mask at 0x1FFFFF00 was the solution.

Comment: Learned something myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pete W answered with the help of the following link : [http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~eg/tele/CanbusIDandMask.html](http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/%7Eeg/tele/CanbusIDandMask.html)

The solution was a filter for 0x300 and a mask of 0x1FFFFF00

Answer (score 1):

If you want as many as 9 out of 13, then acceptance masking is pretty pointless. It is generally an overrated feature of CAN from the time before ["mailbox" CAN controllers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/499348/6102) were invented. The main use of masking is when you expect a whole lot (hundreds) of identifiers on the bus that you aren't interested in.

Acceptance masking tends to make things needlessly complicated, which in turn leads to bugs. In this case you don't need to use neither masks nor mailboxes, just an identifier look-up table in software and sufficiently regular checks of the CAN rx buffers. Keep it simple.

Comment: The problem is that the frequency of the ones I dont want is really fast. I dont want my main processor to have to deal with conditions for these.

Comment: @Adam Then something is off with your design. Most CAN controllers at least have a FIFO buffer option. You just need to empty the (whole) FIFO as regularly as FIFO size multiplied by the time to send a short CAN message with your given baudrate. If your MCU can't handle that requirement, it will go haywire whenever unexpected CAN traffic appears on the bus. If polling is not an option, then as mentioned there are other modern ways to deal with the problem: CAN controller mailboxes or DMA. If that's still not an option, then the problem is that you picked an ancient crappy CAN controller.

Comment: @Adam Also, "CAN to UART" implies that you _must_ act very quickly on every CAN frame to reduce latency overhead caused by your gateway. A gateway firmware can't sit around doing other stuff while there's pending traffic in rx buffers. What MCU and/or CAN controller are you using?